# Having trouble with making embeded video responsive

Tags: html, css

[image]I have made the video responsive, but as you can see when the browser is fully stretched, the width to height ratio is reversed. The iframe is narrow and tall, but when the browser is shrunk and the video goes underneath the text, the ratio corrects itself. How can I fix the ratio in the stretched browser? Here is my code.

```css
.video-responsive {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}

.video-responsive iframe {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 section1Text">
        <h2 class="text-center">What We Have to Offer</h2>
        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel massa iaculis, posuere augue et, pharetra ipsum. Suspendisse metus ex, pellentesque id dolor in, vehicula varius tortor. Nam auctor ante nisi.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="video-responsive">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bsY2GdBEvSA?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, it seems to function exactly like you want it to. Also, use snippets next time instead.

Comment: When the code is run in the browser, the video is placed to the right of the text in the container. For some reason in the snippet, it shows the video underneath the text. I would like to know how to have the video placed besides the text on the right, in the same row.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem either... What is the problem ?

Comment: You're not showing us the relevant CSS. Please update you question to show the CSS controlling the layout of columns/rows.

Comment: I showed all my code. Im positive there is nothing else. I updated the post with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how to have the video placed besides the text on the right, in the same row.

You can achieve this using a `display: flex;` on your `row` class div. Then, setting the `flex-direction` to `row`.

> How can I fix the ratio in the stretched browser?

**EDIT:**
To fill the container while keeping the dimensions of your `iframe`, use the `display: flex` property on the `.video-responsive` div and `flex-basis: 100%;` on the `iframe`:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: hotpink;
}

.video-responsive {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  background: teal;
}

.video-responsive iframe {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.section1Text {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 section1Text">
        <h2 class="text-center">What We Have to Offer</h2>
        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel massa iaculis, posuere augue et, pharetra ipsum. Suspendisse metus ex, pellentesque id dolor in, vehicula varius tortor. Nam auctor ante nisi.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="video-responsive">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bsY2GdBEvSA?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

*note that I've removed the dimensions of the video in the HTML, not sure if that's useful or not...*

---

Here is a [full reference of CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Hope I got it right :)

Comment: For some reason, this did not work for me. It just made the video disappear.

Comment: Weird... It's fully working just on top : https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/1b5a792b-83f5-4f08-be3d-11967e2c666f.png . Have you removed the .video-responsive styling, like I did?

Comment: Ah I didn't even see that. I just tried it, but then it left me off where I first started. The video is no longer responsive.

Comment: Responsive? What do you mean? Have you tried to set a relative width OR height on it ?